# Can AWS EC2 endpoint be used as an endpoint for Google Home?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, actions-on-google, alexa-skills-kit, google-home

I have developed a skill in Amazon Alexa. I have used python along with AWS Lambda and AWS EC2 as an endpoint. I wish to deploy the same skill for Google Home. Can I used the same AWS EC2 as an endpoint in Google Home?

Answer (score 0):

Well... sorta.

While you can use the same AWS Lambda and EC2 instances as the webhook for your [Google Home Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant), the code you have written for Alexa won't magically work for the Google Assistant.

While many of the concepts are similar (Intents, slot filling, getting a JSON request, and having to respond using JSON), some of the details are different. Most notably, the [webhook format](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/build/json) for requests and responses are different.